# One-dimensional Diffusion Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know the diffusion equation is given by

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} $$

if i have a bar on which $ 0<x<L$ with the ends at a temperature equal to zero i have $x=0$ and $x=L$

$$ u(0,t)=0 \quad \quad \quad u(L,t)=0 $$

the initial temperature of the bar at time $t = 0$ is

$$ u(x,0) = f(x) $$ and $$ f(0) = 0 = f(L) $$

I know it's possible to find an ordinary differential equation from this.

But how can I find the value of u(x,t) when the left end of the bar has a temperature of $0^{\circ} C$ and the right end of the bar has a temperature of $100^{\circ} C$?

Comment: What kind of ODE do you get from the homogeneous Dirichlet problem ? If you want to reduce your equation to a homogeneous Dirichlet, you can substract the stationnary solution of the problem, namely $u_{\infty}(x) = 100x$.

Comment: Work with $v(x,t) := u(x,t) - 100x/L$. instead.

Answer (score 1):

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/heateqnnonzero.aspx

I'll refer you to that because it's clearer than anything I could write quickly. In any case, they solve the problem by subtracting the steady state temperature profile from the solution so that you are now solving a PDE for the function $v\left(x,t\right)=u\left(x,t\right)-u_{ss}\left(x\right)$. Here, $u_{ss}$ is the profile you get by solving the ODE that results from setting the time derivative term to zero.